# Php variable to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How to add the value of php variabele to jquery variable and adds them,i have a form that will  take a value and post to second page where second page contains a div panel where the form checkboxes values are adding and subtracting,basically i want to add the submitted value from page1 to page2.Here is the code.I have 3 form values which will be redirected one by one.Whenever user submits the respective button

```
if($_POST['submit'])
{
$beg=$_POST['basic'];
}

function refreshPrices() {

    var currentTotalValue = 0;
    var beg=?????
    $("#results div").each(function() {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt($(this).find("span").text().substring(1)))) {
            currentTotalValue += parseInt($(this).find("span").text().substring(1));
        }
    });


    $("#totalValue").text("$" + currentTotalValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var beg = '<?php echo $beg ;?>';
```

if you want to add to the total value you can do this:

```
currentTotalValue = currentTotalValue + parseInt(beg);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var beg=<?php echo $beg; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to do it this way :

```
var js_var = '<?=json_encode($php_var);?>';
```

This way you will be able to transfer any type of data to js (arrays, objects, strings, etc.) and access it easily like this:

```
js_var['element']
```

Comment: Is this a correct code currentTotalValue = currentTotalValue + parseInt(beg) + parseInt(int) + parseInt(adv);

Comment: So? I don't say that it's the only possible solution. I was just truing to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var beg = '<?php echo $beg ;?>';
```

**But this can be only one once during the load of the page. After that we cant assign a server side script to js.**

Comment: Is this a correct code currentTotalValue = currentTotalValue + parseInt(beg) + parseInt(int) + parseInt(adv);

Comment: on condition that beg,int and adv are js variables

Comment: var beg = '<?php echo $beg ;?>'; var inte = '<?php echo $int ;?>'; var adv = '<?php echo $adv ;?>';

Comment: are you doing this only during page load? I mean this operation is done once?

Comment: php post variables,only adding 1 variable i-e beg to this code currentTotalValue = currentTotalValue + parseInt(beg) + parseInt(int) + parseInt(adv);

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7XfNQ/,if i use single value i-e beg it is working fine but when i add two more variables to currentTotalValue = currentTotalValue + parseInt(beg);(working fine) but not this + urrentTotalValue = currentTotalValue + parseInt(beg) +parseInt(int) + parseInt(adv);

Comment: The code you have shown in the question does not contain int and adv.Please update question for better understanding for us to answer

Comment: try `alert(inte);    alert(advn);` and tell me what value is printed there

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve value by input class or id like dat

var beg = $("#basic").val();